# Cannot get wkhtmltopdf.exe working in IIS8.5/Windows Server 2012 environment

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, iis-8.5

Very frustrating!  It works on my dev machine just fine, but when deployed to remote server I just get a blank grey page with a small "loading" message (the animated gif does not run) in the bottom left: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kEes.png

I get no errors in the browser console. I haven't seen any errors on the server logs either although I may not have sufficient logging level enabled - I don't know.

I'm running version: `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1-9615f00 (with patched qt)` which I access by running `./wkhtmltopdf.exe -V` at the command prompt.

Anyone got any ideas what I could try to get this working please?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I still don't know the problem I had but I cured it by changing the app pool to run under "Localsystem" instead of "ApplicationPoolIdentity".